# Region projection of multivariable interpolated function

Tags: plotting

I have a problem plotting a multivariable interpolated function when projected into two-dimensions using `Resolve` and `RegionPlot`.

I found the interpolation for a 5-variable list of data, which I call `F[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5]` (the interpolation works fine), where the `xi` are my variables. I want to plot a region for `F` satisfying certain condition, i.e., between two numbers and then project onto a two-variable plane, say `{x1, x2}`. I can do this when I fix the value of the rest of the variables, but I want to project onto `x1, x2` the valid region of `F` for all of the values admitted by the rest of my parameters. My code looks something like this:

```
  ImpReg = 
    ImplicitRegion[-1 < F[x1, x2, x3, x4, x5] < 1, 
      {{x1, 1, 200}, {x2, 500, 5000}, {x3, 1, 351}, {x4, 1000, 4000}, {x5, 1, 4}]
  graph = 
    RegionPlot[
      Resolve[Exists[{x3, x4, x5}, {x1, x2, x3, x4, x5} ∈ ImpReg], Reals],
      {x1, 1, 200}, {x2, 500, 5000}]
```

By the way, I followed the example given in *Mathematica* documentation for "Formula Region Projections" the only difference being that they do not use an interpolated function, but I do not see why this should be the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The calculation fails, because `Resolve` cannot handle an `InterpolatingFunction`.  To illustrate, consider the simple problem,

```
f[x1_, x2_, x3_] := x1^2 + x2^2 + x3^2
ImpReg = ImplicitRegion[f[x1, x2, x3] < 1, {{x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, {x3, -2, 2}}];
RegionPlot[Resolve[Exists[{x3}, {x1, x2, x3} \[Element] ImpReg], Reals], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}]
```

[image]

Next, define an `InterpolatingFunction`.

```
g = FunctionInterpolation[f[x1, x2, x3], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, {x3, -2, 2}]
```

`g` is well behaved, as can be seen from a plot of it.

```
RegionPlot3D[ImpReg]
```

[image]

Yet, as the OP observed,

```
ImpReg = ImplicitRegion[g[x1, x2, x3] < 1, {{x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}, {x3, -2, 2}}]
RegionPlot[Resolve[Exists[{x3}, {x1, x2, x3} \[Element] ImpReg], Reals], {x1, -2, 2}, {x2, -2, 2}]
```

produces an empty plot.  To see why, evaluate `Resolve` for the definition of `ImpReg` using `f`.

```
Resolve[Exists[{x3}, {x1, x2, x3} \[Element] ImpReg], Reals]
(* x1 <= 2 && x1 >= -2 && x2 <= 2 && x2 >= -2 && x1^2 + x2^2 < 1 *)
```

while for the definition of `ImpReg` using `g` it returns unevaluated.  To plot the projecton of `g` onto the {x,y} plane, it would be necessary to develop an appropriate projection function, because `Resolve` is not up to it.

Conceptually, such a projection operator would involve solving g[x1,x2,x3] numerically for, say, `x2` as a function of `{x1, x3}`, maximizing and minimizing `x2` over `x3` as a function of `x1`, and then plotting the maximum and minimum values of `x2` as functions of `x1`.  Alternatively, one could take numerous constant `x3` slices through `g`, constructing the `RegionUnion` of them, and generating a `RegionPlot` of the result.  Either approach is slow in 2D and slower still in 5D.

Alternatively, if the surface of the numerically defined region is simple enough, it might be possible to fit an analytical function to it, which `Resolve` presumably could then handle.

Comment: Thanks!, I suspected ImplicitFunction was the one that could not handle interpolated functions, this is useful.